# JFX alert.showAndWait() is called to soon

Tags: java, javafx

I have an JFX application.
I loop through a list and want a confirmation for some of the items before to continue.
However, because somewhere deep down the code a new thread or new service is created, the loop almost runs in parallel.
When the confirmation button appears for example for testcase2, the processing of testcase1 has not even started.

Here is my code

```
...
        for (EBICSTestcase testcase : testCaseOrderList) {
           doSingleTestcase(testcase);          
        }
...
    private void doSingleTestcase(EBICSTestcase testcase) {      
        OrderParameters orderParameters = new OrderParameters();
        orderParameters.setBankAccess(CBTCbankAccess.getValue());
        orderParameters.setUser(CBTCuser.getValue());
        orderParameters.setAction(testcase.getTransferDirect());
        orderParameters.setOrderType(testcase.getOrdertype());
        orderParameters.setFileName(testcase.getSendfile());                   
        logger.debug("run: {} transferDirect: {} filename: {}", testcase.getOrdertype(), testcase.getTransferDirect(), testcase.getSendfile());
        if (testcase.getConfirmationText() != null) {
            if (! showConfirmation(testcase.getConfirmationText())) {
                logger.warn("skipped run!");
                return;
            }
        }
        doSingleRun(orderParameters, 1);        
        logger.exit();
    }
    private boolean showConfirmation(String confirmationText) {

        boolean doContinue = false;
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Confirmation");
        alert.setHeaderText(confirmationText);

        Optional<ButtonType> option = alert.showAndWait();

        if (option.get() == null) {
            logger.info("No selection!");
        } else if (option.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
            logger.info("OK!");
            doContinue=true;
        } else if (option.get() == ButtonType.CANCEL) {
            logger.info("Cancelled!");
        } else {
            logger.error("unknown button option");
        }
        return doContinue;
    }
```

Comment: What do you actually want to happen? Do you want to wait for the previous task to complete before prompting about the next one?

Comment: Yes, task1 runs without confirmation. Task2 shall start after task1 is finished and after confirmation by user via UI (after task1 is finished).

Comment: Can you add a callback to a task to be notified of when it's finished?

Comment: Can you share the code from doSingleRun I don't see any threads being created in the code you've provided so it's probably coming from there

Comment: Its a lot of code and the thread creation is very deep down. But I want to stop the processing of the code immediately in the loop, because than I'm in the JFX thread and can open new windows.
Otherwise I get an IlegalStateException